# Gallery program for linux?

Tags: software-recommendation

On my android phone, I have [simple gallery pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplemobiletools.gallery.pro) installed, I was looking for a similar application for Ubuntu or for Gnu-Debian based systems in general.
I couldn't find such an app, I just need a normal photo & video gallery app for Ubuntu the same way we have on our IOS or android phones.
Any suggestion?

Comment: How about `Shotwell` (name of the package is `shotwell`)?

Answer (score 0):

There is [gThumb](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gthumb) app which has a simple and modern UI like your example.

You can install it with apt basically:

```
sudo apt install gthumb
```